# Tkinter / TTK - Prevent string to ButtonPress conversion

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I'm writing a simple script that creates a ttk `Treeview` (that acts as a table) and, when you double-click it, it opens a file (with the path saved in the dictionary). However, when you double-click a row you'll get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",
line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Maicol\Documents\Projects\App_WINDOWS\School_Life_Diary\note.py",
line 195, in <lambda>
    lambda f=nt[x]["URIallegato"]: os.startfile(str(f)))
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Can't find the specified file: '<ButtonPress event state=Mod1 num=1 x=677 y=37>'
```

The problem is this code:

```
t.bind("<Double-1>", lambda f=nt[x]["URIallegato"]: os.startfile(str(f)))
```

that allows the double-clicking and opening of the file.

Here is the full `Treeview` code:

```
t=Treeview(w)
t.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
for x in list(nt.keys()):
    t.insert("",x,text=nt[x]["allegati"])
    if nt[x]["allegati"]!="":
        t.bind("<Double-1>",
               lambda f=nt[x]["URIallegato"]: os.startfile(str(f)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the event fires, tkinter will pass along an event object. You are trying to open that event object as if it were a file.

Why is that? Let's start by rewriting your lambda as a proper function. Your lambda is the equivalent of this function:

```
def handle_event(f=default_value):
    os.startfile(str(default_value))
```

When the event fires, it does the equivalent of this:

```
handle_event(event)
```

Your script is given a single positional argument, `event`, which is assigned to the first keyword argument. Thus `f` is the same as `event`.

The solution is to make sure your `lambda` accepts the event, which it can simply ignore:

```
lambda event, f=nt[x]["URIallegato"]: os.startfile(str(f)))
```

With the above, the `event` object will be associated with the `event` parameter, and your default value for `f` will be passed as `f`.

Comment: i was going with this too, but it seems all binding are overridden by the last value ?

Comment: @PRMoureu: I don't understand your comment. When you create a binding, that function will automatically be passed one positional argument. How that gets interpreted is based on the standard rules of python.

Comment: Sure, but the events are bound to the Treeview in the loop, so what event is triggered in different lines ?

Comment: @PRMoureu: I don't understand your question. The event is triggered when you double-click. I don't know what you mean by "in different lines". Lines of code? Lines (rows) in the treeview widget?

Comment: It's very simple: when you do something that triggers an event, tkinter will call the function you supplied. It will _always_ pass one positional argument.

Comment: this is how i interpret the OP : [https://repl.it/LsbT/0](https://repl.it/LsbT/0), only 'event 3' is printed

Comment: Only one question: If I want that every single clickable row has a different result... is binding of every single row possible? Thanks

Comment: @MaicolBatti: no, but that's  probably not what you really want. Normally a single click will select  a row, and the double-click should ask the tree for which row is selected and act upon that row.

Comment: No, I mean... every row has an ID and with this ID I can get (by a pre-compiled dictionary) the path of the file to open. When I click on a row it opens the file of the latest row inserted. What I want is open different files for any row. Is it possible?

Comment: @MaicolBatti: yes. Like I said, the original click will select a row, so when the double click is processed you can query the row that was clicked and get its associated data.

Comment: Ok, but if in the lambda I use `t.item(t.focus())`, I get a dictionary with empty values...

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't designed for extended discussions. If you have another question, click the "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is about creating a binding for the `Treeview` in the loop.

There is only one *double click event* that can be declared and triggered for the tree, not one by row, and here you are overriding it in each iteration.

---

This lambda pattern is known to declare *commands* for widgets inside a for/loop, and it works fine for this purpose:

```
lambda f=nt[x]["URIallegato"]: os.startfile(str(f))
```

But here you declare a default parameter `f`, and the lambda will be executed with an `event` argument given by the event binding, that's what you get in the exception : `<ButtonPress event state=Mod1...`

Anyway, we saw that this won't work in your case even if you fix the lambda with a second parameter to accept the `event` without replacing your default value `f`.

---

What i suggest is to use the `values` field of each row to store the information `URIallegato"` without displaying the column in the tree.

And then you can bind a generic event to the Treeview, by using `focus()` to get the selected item, and extract the value to get URI.

```
t=Treeview(w)
t.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

def open_item(event):
    item = t.item(t.focus())
    if item['text']:
        os.startfile(item['values'][0])

for x in list(nt.keys()):
    value = ''
    if nt[x]["allegati"]:
        value = str(nt[x]["URIallegato"])
    t.insert("",x,text=nt[x]["allegati"], values=value)

t.bind("<Double-1>", open_item)
```

A lambda could hardly be used here if you want to check if there is an URI to open.