# Different tkinter binding for any ttk treeview row

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, bind, ttk

I'm writing a simple script that create a ttk treeview (that act as a table) and, when you double-click it, it opens a file (with the path saved in the dictionary). Double click opening is possible by this method:

```
t.bind("<Double-1>", lambda f=nt[x]["URIallegato"]: os.startfile(str(f)))
```

However, this doesn't gave me the ID of the row (stored in the `#0` column). With the ID I can get the path of the file saved in a dictionary.
Here is the full `Treeview` code:

```
t=Treeview(w)
t.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
for x in list(nt.keys()):
    t.insert("",x,text=nt[x]["allegati"])
    if nt[x]["allegati"]!="":
        t.bind("<Double-1>",
               lambda f=nt[x]["URIallegato"]: os.startfile(str(f)))
```

Thanks!

Comment: you are overriding the binding method to the Treeview `t`, i provided an answer in your last question...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter / TTK - Prevent string to ButtonPress conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46506048/tkinter-ttk-prevent-string-to-buttonpress-conversion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way to do this is to bind a single binding on the treeview for a double click. The default binding for single-click will select the item, and in your double-click binding you can ask the treeview for the selected item.

If you associate values with the treeview item, you can fetch them so that you don't have to store them in a dictionary.

Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def on_double_click(event):
    item_id = event.widget.focus()
    item = event.widget.item(item_id)
    values = item['values']
    url = values[0]
    print("the url is:", url)

root = tk.Tk()
t=ttk.Treeview(root)
t.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

t.bind("<Double-Button-1>", on_double_click)

for x in range(10):
    url = "http://example.com/%d" % x
    text = "item %d" % x
    t.insert("", x,  text=text, values=[url])

root.mainloop()
```